# Node js mysql Running into the ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

New to js and node and I've got an app.js that will query a database and I query it using a pool so I have a file called db.js that looks like this

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const config = {db: {host: 'localhost',user: 'root',password: '',database: 'school',port:'3308',waitForConnections: true,connectionLimit: 2,queueLimit: 0,},};

const pool = mysql.createPool(config.db);

async function query(sql, params) {

const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql, params);

return rows;

}

module.exports = {query,}
```

However after running docker-compose --build in the terminal I run into this error

`/src/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:359`

`test-app-1         |     const localErr = new Error();`

`test-app-1         |                      ^`

`test-app-1         |`

`test-app-1         | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3308`

`test-app-1         |     at PromisePool.execute (/src/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:359:22)`

`test-app-1         |     at Object.query (/src/app/services/db.js:20:39)`

`test-app-1         |     at /src/app/app.js:17:8`

`test-app-1         |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)`

`test-app-1         |     at next (/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)`

`test-app-1         |     at Route.dispatch (/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)`

`test-app-1         |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)`

`test-app-1         |     at /src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22`

`test-app-1         |     at Function.process_params (/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341:12)`

`test-app-1         |     at next (/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) {`

`test-app-1         |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',`

`test-app-1         |   errno: -111,`

`test-app-1         |   sql: undefined,`

`test-app-1         |   sqlState: undefined,`

`test-app-1         |   sqlMessage: undefined`

`test-app-1         | }`

The requests that don't require the database open fine e.g http://127.0.0.1:3000/ but the ones that do query the database fall to this error. I can see the error stems from a file in a module but I don't know how to go about fixing this. My code for requests in my app.js file look like this

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

res.send("Main Page");});

app.get('/class', function(req,res) {

var sql = 'SELECT * FROM class ';

db.query(sql).then(results => {

console.log(results);

res.json(results);});})
```

And my index.js file looks like this

```
"use strict";
console.log("entrypoint");
const app = require("./app/app.js");
```

I notice the error stems from a module file but I don't want to tamper with it due to my inexperience.

Comment: Please don't use a root user to connect to mysql, event in development server. Instead create a mysql user with the strict necessary rights

Comment: And don't leave root password blank if it's the case

Comment: Your error message seems to be an mysql conection error. Have you try to use your lysql information with mysql command to verify access to the mysql server?

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running? The error suggests not

Comment: @Alaindeseine With regards to your first 2 suggestions I have changed xampp from config to cookie settings so that I could see login option. I have then made a new account for the database that has all priviledges and no empty password but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Alaindeseine With regards to your 3rd comment I don't understand what you mean or what I should do

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa I'm using xampp and it is running

Comment: use a mysql command to test you credentials:
``mysql -u myuser -p mypassword -h myhost mydatabase``
If all 4 information are ok you will connect, if not you have a problme with your credentials

Comment: @Alaindeseine I believe I connected a lot of data printed in the shell so I don't think there is a credentials problem

Comment: Have you verified that port 3308 is open?

Comment: @Alaindeseine It wasn't however I was using 3306 before which is open and I have now tried a further 2 more open tcp ports after your comment but no luck

Comment: @Ursula are you saying that MySQL is running on 3308? Because that's where the node app is connecting to

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa the app was running on port 3000 and MySQL was tried on 3306,3308,135,80

Comment: Definitely, your error is about connecting to your mysql server. So you should test to verify what information make connection to be refused.

Try replace ``host: 'localhost'`` by ``host: '127.0.0.1'`` in your config object

Comment: I have done so but still the same error, are you familiar with docker? If you're sure the error is in the connection the fault may lay within my docker-compose file

Comment: It's not a docker error i guess You have to test/verify what ip/port mysql is using, if user/password is ok and if datablase exists.

Comment: ``connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3308 `` indicate that ``test-app-1`` can't connect tp mysql and that ip 127.0.0.1 and port 3308 are used for this try

Comment: A bit of a reach but if I upload my files onto a public github repository could you take a look and see if it runs on your machine?

Comment: Oh wait. If this is in a docker container then localhost does not resolve to the local machine. Try replacing localhost with "host.docker.internal", leave the port as 3308. Note that this is for local use only, once u take your app to production, use the actual ip of the MySQL server.

Comment: Manged to get help solving it, I was using xampp to connect to phpmyadmin and that was running on a different port to what I specified in my files so once some changes were made I just had to go to localhost:8081 to login where I could now query the db once I uploaded it. You were correct with regards to the port issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using docker containers for the app and mysql server, and in the error you shared is written:

```
| Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3308
```

To me seems, your docker's trying to connect to port 3308 in your app container instead of connecting to mysql container.

It seems a docker-composer configuration problem.